# DFT of 2D double array using fftw3 r2c comparing to c2c

Tags: gaussian, fftw

I am trying to understand how to use the "fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d". First, I generate a matrix with a non symmetric gaussian (`sigma_x != sigma_y`) and I make the fft using `fftw_plan_dft_c2c_2D`. But it requires a temporary fftw_complexe array where I just copy the gaussian matrix and set the imaginary part to 0.0.

[image: gaussian matrix] [image: resulting c2c 2D fft]

In order to save some memory, I am trying to avoid the temporary fftw_complexe and use directly the "fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2D" expecting the same "half" result.
[image: 2D fft of gaussian using r2c]

It looks like I missing something.. can anyone help please ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the center frequency for the inverse transformation as described here for numpy:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html